# How to set a variable in these batch loops?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scope, batch-processing, findstr

think I'm getting things confused here.

I've got a loop that runs all files in a folder

```
for /f "delims=_" %%J in ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.ext /c "cmd /c echo @path"')
    do start "program"  /D "c:\program files\path\to\program" /Wait program -r  %%J
```

`%%J` should represent each file if I've set this up / interpretted this correctly.

I have another loop that is looking in the xml code for each of these files and searching for a particular pattern using `findstr` and parsing out the Name from some tags like this:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr /n /i "<Name>ABCDir" "%%J"')
    do (set name=%%a)
echo !name!
```

Now I thought it would be as easy as just reusing `%%J` in the `findstr` loop but it doesn't seem to be working. When I run the code, it tells me `FINDSTR: Cannot open %J` and then `ECHO is off`

I'm guessing my problem is that it was too quick and easy to try using `%%J` in the next loop and that the shell isn't connecting the dots between loops.

Any ideas how I can do this? Because I need the file name in the `findstr` loop to always match the file in the first loop.

**EDIT:** Here's what the file might look like.

```
c:\path\to\the file name
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open "c:\path\
FINDSTR: Cannot open to\
FINDSTR: Cannot open the
FINDSTR: Cannot open file
FINDSTR: Cannot open name
```

so it would seem its a simple issue of how the shell is reading the %%J variable. This type of thing has shown up when I've forgotten to put quotes around file names before but the quotations are around %%J. I even tried double quotations but was a little relieved when that didn't fix it.

**EDIT2:** I changed

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr /n /i "<Name>ABCDir" "%%J"')
    do (set name=%%a)
```

to

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr /n /i "<Name>ABCDir" "%%~nJ"')
    do (set name=%%a)
```

and now the output is: `FINDSTR: Cannot open the file name`. So now at least its reading the file in full. At least it would seem that way.

Comment: You would need to show us exactly the code you were using to produce the fail condition. Just edit it into the question you've posted.

Comment: The code in my post is the only code that is relevant to the script not working. I'm tested it enough to know that its only this little segment not doing its job (well at least its the only segment contributing to this part not doing its job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %%J in ( ... ) do  (
    ....
    %%J is visible here, inside the do clause
    ....
) <- here %%J goes out of scope
```

So, you can include your second (third : `%%F`?) `for` loop inside the `do` clause of the first one

```
for %%J in ("%%F\*.ext") do (
    start "program"  /D "c:\program files\path\to\program" /Wait program -r  "%%~fJ"
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr /n /i "<Name>ABCDir" "%%J"') do (
        echo %%a
    )
)
```

Comment: could you explain why you changed `/Wait program -r %%J` to `/Wait program -r "%%~fJ"`?

Comment: That is `FOR` variable reference substitution.  `~f` expands `%%J` to its fully qualified path.  Type `help for` in a console and see the last couple of pages for a full explanation of this type of syntax.

Comment: This syntax isn't reading `%%J` correctly in the second loop. I posted an edit to my original post to show what is happening.

Comment: That's because `%%~nJ` contains only the basename of `%%J` without extension.  If you want to include the extension (and yes, you do want this), use `%%~nxJ`.  Or better yet, use `%%~fJ` to specify the fully qualified path.  No reason not to.  Also, you should put `do (` on the previous line, like MC ND's example.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked for some reason. Last time `%%~fJ` was actually opening the program up outside of the shell