# How do I set and check a boolean variable in a for loop in a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm pretty new to windows batch files so I'm sure this question has an obvious answer but I've been digging around online for hours and haven't been able to find it. **When I run the following batch file, why doesn't it output *"It worked!"*?**

```
@echo OFF
SET /A _Converted="0"
SET _Converted
IF _Converted==0 (echo It worked!) ELSE (echo it didn't work)
```

Output:

```
_Converted=0
it didn't work
```

But sometimes (I'm not sure how to reproduce), it outputs:

```
Environment variable _Converted not defined
```

Here's what I've tried:

- [`SET` vs `SET /A`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- Quotes in different places (`SET /A "_Converted=0"` vs. `SET /A _Converted="0"`)
  *"If you use any of the logical or modulus operators, you will need to enclose the expression string in quotes."*
- My problem is in a for loop but I can reproduce the issue outside of the loop so I don't think [delayed variable expansion](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622676/how-to-set-a-variable-in-these-batch-loops) helps me even though they initially looked similar.

Comment: `IF %_Converted%==0 (echo It worked!) ...`

Comment: However, if previous line is located inside a FOR loop, it requires Delayed Expansion: `IF !_Converted!==0 (echo It worked!) ...`

Answer (score 0):

**Put %'s around the variable before checking its value. Use delayed expansion if in a loop**

As @Aacini mentioned in his comment, the following prints *"It worked!"*:

```
@echo OFF
SET /A _Converted="0"
SET _Converted
IF %_Converted%==0 (echo It worked!) ELSE (echo it didn't work)
```

The problem was that my original issue was within a for loop and I messed with the `IF` statement before moving it into a simpler batch file to try to isolate the problem. So my fix will be to combine this answer with [delayed variable expansion](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php).